# Xml Schema: Nodes with same name but different types based on attribute value

Tags: xml, schema

I need a schema that accomplished this:

```
<object type="possession">
  <property name="VIN">1111111111111111</property>
  <property name="Year">2003</property>
  <property name="Make">Chevrolet</property>
</object>
```

- The "VIN" property must be 17 characters
- The "Year property must be of type gYear
- The "Make" property must conform to an enumeration of {Ford, Chevrolet, Mazda}

---

**Right now I have this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="object">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="property" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="VinType"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="property" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="YearType"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="property" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="MakeType"></xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


  <!-- Vehicle Identification number (VIN) -->
  <xs:simpleType name="VinRestriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length fixed="true" value="17"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="VinType" mixed="true">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="VinRestriction">
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="VIN" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>


  <!-- Vehicle Year -->
  <xs:simpleType name="YearRestriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:gYear"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="YearType" mixed="true">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="YearRestriction">
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="Year" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- Vehicle Make -->
  <xs:simpleType name="MakeRestriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Chevrolet"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Ford"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Mazda"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="MakeType" mixed="true">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="MakeRestriction">
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="Make" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a well known restriction of XSD 1.0 that you can't do this: the type of an element is determined solely by the element. The problem is often called "co-occurrence constraints" and if you search on this term you will find plenty of references.

It can be done in XSD 1.1 using the new facility of "conditional type assignment". XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Xerces (beta) and Saxon (EE 9.4).

Another way to tackle the problem is to do validation using a pipeline that first does a transformation, then validates. The transformation would typically change `<property name="VIN">1111111111111111</property>` to `<VIN>11111111111111111</VIN>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aware of all of this; I was looking for a concrete example of how to accomplish my goal. I am currently testing the alternatives provided by the functionality of 1.1 but am struggling with it. I have also considered the option of transformation and would like to avoid it if possible for my current project.